# How to start service to do something repeatedly in android

Tags: java, android, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android regular task (cronjob equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266878/android-regular-task-cronjob-equivalent)

I am currently trying following code to perform a task on daily basis

```
public class BackupService extends Service {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startBackup();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startBackup() {

        Date date = new Date(time);
        System.out.println("Backup time:" +date);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new BackupTimerTask(), date,
                delayTime());
    }

    private long delayTime() {

        long delay = 86400000;
            System.out.println("delay time:" + delay);
        return delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if (timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  private class BackupTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Backup started");
            //starting backup here
        }

    }

}
```

and I am calling this service as

```
startService(new Intent(this, BackupService.class));
```

This is working fine if I put short interval like 5 minute, but this is not working on long inteval. And if I go to running services in android apps then i can see my service is in running state. I think probably something is wrong with timertask class. How I can solve my problem??

Comment: What you probably want is using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Milos makes some good points, but please don't make your service a Foreground service.  Instead, use AlarmManager.  There are several related issues that you can take a look at:

[Android AlarmManager - Scheduling a recurring Intent to fire off twice a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762934/android-alarmmanager-scheduling-a-recurring-intent-to-fire-off-twice-a-day)

[AlarmManager not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684077/alarmmanager-not-working/10685132#10685132)

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in Android there are no "unkillable tasks" who can be executed with 100% guarantee.
If you take a look in android lifecycle management, if the device needs resources, the system will kill some unused or old tasks running.

This is the same for android services. A service has a greater privilege as a simple task, but the service can still be killed by the system.

The problem in your case is probably that when you are setting the timer to be 5min, your service is running correctly. The problem arrives when you considerably increase the time. Then, the chance that the service will be killed is much bigger: See http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/

So, you will have to consider another approach to acheave your goal. One of the solutions, but still without 100% guarantee, is to use  foreground services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground