# Android alarm manager not working two times everyday

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I need to alarm manager to repeat two times everyday and for that i used  2 calendar objects for two different time but its only work for first time not for second

**MainActivity**

```
       public void startEvent(View view) {

            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14); 
            cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
            cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

**BroadCastReciver**

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Send Location to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("test");
        myRef.push().setValue("New Location Received");

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AlarmManager - Scheduling a recurring Intent to fire off twice a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762934/android-alarmmanager-scheduling-a-recurring-intent-to-fire-off-twice-a-day)

Comment: but what is wrong with my code why second time is not working ?

Comment: Maybe, because You test after 14:30? add `cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` and it should work for the next day

Comment: i need two callback for each day at two different times

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent; 
PendingIntent pIntent; 
AlarmManager alarmManager;

        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal_now.setTime(date);



private void alarmOne(){
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal_alarm.setTime(date);
                    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14); 
                    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                    cal1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);

if(cal1.before(cal_now)){
            // Move to tomorrow for first alarm
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cal1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
}

private void alarmTwo(){


Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal2.setTime(date);
                    cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
                    cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                    cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                    cal2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);



        if(cal2.before(cal_now)){
            // Move to tomorrow for second alarm
            cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }


pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cal2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
}
```

Comment: because you are try to fire alarm on same alarm id...You have to give each pending intent have different id's. i edited my answer

Comment: when two call alarmTwo, alarmOne ?

Comment: call it together.. where ever you want to call

Comment: and  cal_now.setTime(date); what date i need to pass here

Answer (score 0):

Try this send Hours and minutes

```
public static void setAlarmforOverlay(Context context, int hour, int minute, int AlarmId) {    
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("hour", hour);
        intent.putExtra("minute", minute);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmId, intent, 0);
        //1 PM and 0 AM
        int AM_PM;
        if (hour < 12)
            AM_PM = 0;
        else
            AM_PM = 1;


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, AM_PM);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

Usage

```
setAlarmforOverlay(mContext,14,00,1);
setAlarmforOverlay(mContext,14,30,2);
```

Also verify Manifest

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".YourBroadCastReceiver"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```