# Delete specific Alarm from AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentfilter

I want to delete an Alarm which i have set in a Broadcastreceiver.
this it how it should execute:

I receive a GCM message, which contains an user_state field.

```
if user_state is 0 no notification is triggered
if user_state is 1 a notification is triggered
if user_state is 2 an Alarm is set and the notification is triggered 20 Minutes later.
```

This all works well.

Now I want to delete an specific Alarm, depending on the Data received from the GCM-intent.
Unfortunately AlarmManager.cancel() does not compare Extra fields.
I also tried to use intent.setType("data to compare") but if I set this field the Broadcast is not received...

I have now tried to register a new BroadcastReceiver with the Data which should be compared in the Action field. 
As I understand, this should work fine, BUT it is not possible to register a BroadcastReceiver from within a BroadcastReceiver.

Also it is not possible to get a list of Pendingintents from the AlarmManager.
So all i can do now is delete ALL alarms - which is not an option,

The only other idea I have is using my own Service instead of the AlarmManager... I would like to avoid that one. I don't want to use extra Resources when there is an buildin Option.

Here is my set Alarm Method:

```
private void setTimed(Intent intent, Notify notify) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    bundle.remove("userstate");
    bundle.putString("userstate", "3");

    Intent ringintent = new Intent("de.pluetzner.waveobserver.TRECEIVE");
    ringintent.setType(notify.getHost()+"&&&"+notify.getService());
    ringintent.putExtras(bundle);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.context.getSystemService(this.context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, ringintent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (this.waittime * 60 * 1000), pi);
    Log.d("timer", "time set");
}
```

The ringintent.setType() should be an identifier for the alarm but that does not work.
Without this the Alarm is received

This one here is the Method to delete an Alarm.

```
private void deleteAlarm(Intent intent, Notify notify) {
    Intent ringintent = new Intent("de.pluetzner.waveobserver.TRECEIVE");
    ringintent.setType(notify.getHost() + "&&&" + notify.getService());
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, ringintent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.context.getSystemService(this.context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
    Log.d("timer", "time removed");
}
```

It is the same here - with setType set it does not work. Without it, it deletes every Alarm.

I also know that it would be a somehow abusive use of setType - but I am out of Ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5055517/718

Comment: Sure? as far as i understand i would also need to rebuild the exact same PendingIntent - which leaves me with the same Problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RequestCode parameter of [getBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) method uniquely identify each PendingIntent.

You could assign an Unique integer code for each PendingIntent.

Alarm1:

```
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 1, ringintent, 0);
```

Alarm2:

```
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 2, ringintent, 0);
```

Now if you want to kill Alarm2 alone, recreate the PendingIntent with same identifier and then call cancel method of AlarmManager

```
      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: I am honestly not sure if this would solve the problem. Its been a long time since I worked on this app. Ill accept your answer anyways :D