# Receive notification every five minutes and stop when click on it

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I want to tell the user he has something to do every 5 minutes. I receive a notification every 5 minutes. But my problem is that I don't know where I can stop it. (I want to stop it when the user has click on the notification).

Here is my code in my Activity :

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, heure);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), minute*60*1000+heure*3600*1000,  sender);
```

and here is my code for my BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "debut receive");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,
            PiecesPasEnvoyesActivity.class);

    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.courier_blanc)
    .setContentTitle("Messages à envoyer")
    .setContentText("Vous avez des messages à envoyer");

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = 001;

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Application.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notification add a pending intent and have this intent stop the receiver.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityToStopReciever.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.courier_blanc)
    .setContentTitle("Messages à envoyer")
    .setContentIntent(intent)
    .setContentText("Vous avez des messages à envoyer");
```

In the ActivityToStopReciever.class take a look at this link to cancel the notification

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int

and look here for removing the alarm

[Android AlarmManager problem with setting & resetting an alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963271/android-alarmmanager-problem-with-setting-resetting-an-alarm/5055517#5055517)

Comment: so i have to create a new activity in which one I cancel the notification. But how can I get the ID of the notification ?

Comment: You set the id when you make the notification.